# Meteor async function for validateLoginAttempt

Tags: meteor, async-await

I wan't to use googles captcha as an security messure in my app.

The process:

1. Request public response from google on client (Success)
2. Save public response to an collection (Success)
3. On server validateLoginAttempt should send my secret and client aclaimed public keys for validation (Success)
4. If and only if 3 successfull return true otherwise false. (Fails)

The problem I am facing is in 4

I need to execute validateLoginAttempt as async, As soon as I write:

```
    Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(async() => {
      await myCallToRemoteValidation
    })
```

However

```
Accounts.validateLoginAttempt(() => {...})
```

does process the callback, but too late since node will have already progressed. I already use async await in other parts of the code, and it works but not with accounts. How can I solve this?

Reference: http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsServer-validateLoginAttempt

Comment: Could you show the code of your `myCallToRemoteValidation` function as well?

Comment: Have you tried with fibers/future?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?